# How to uninstall Google Drive PC?

Tags: google-drive

I installed Google Drive PC in the hope that it would let me copy Google Drive folders without doing an upload/download. "Sync" forces an automatic download/upload, which won't work for me. How can I uninstall Google Drive PC?

Comment: See [Uninstall Google Drive for your Mac/PC - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375081?hl=en)

Comment: Since this is about the installable Google Drive sync tool, and not the web interface, this question is better for [su].

Answer (score 2):

Ok If you're on a windows 10, 8 or 8.1 follow these steps:

1. Press windows buttons  and "x" at the same time.
2. Then press p. It should open the control panel.
3. Then find google drive. Double click it and it will start to uninstall.

If you're on windows 7 or if the steps above didn't work follow these:

1. press start then control panel
2. then `uninstall a program`
3. find `google drive`. Double click it and it will start to uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

Steps from google support [page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375081) to uninstall google drive

1. Click Start and then Control Panel or Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type 'control' , then Click OK.
2. Click Programs and then Programs
   and Features
3. Click Backup and Sync from Google and then Uninstall.
4. Click Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a problem uninstalling it, Microsoft has a windows fix tool that helps to uninstall a stubborn program:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed

> [Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed)
>   Applies to:   Windows 10, Windows 7, Windows 8.1
>
> ﻿Follow these steps to automatically repair issues (including
>   corrupted registry keys) that block you from installing or removing
>   programs:

Answer (score -1):

The trick is depending on your OS and version select the following to uninstall:

Either (1 - Backup and Sync from Google and then Uninstall) or (2 - Google Drive)

I confess i missed the top one as they changed the name from the bottom one and was pretty pissed off.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Could you expand on your answer with specifics?  original answer mentioned "Depending on your OS and version"